# Parsing Nginx's http_userid_module cookie in Python

Tags: python, nginx, binary-data

I've set nginx userid module to produce uid cookies on requests to the server for anonymous tracking, While everything goes as expected with setting the cookies, I can't figure out how these cookies should be parsed (in Python) for further analysis.

According the nginx's docs (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_userid_module.html#userid_service) the http_userid_module is fully compliant with apache's mod_uid and according to apache's mod_uid docs (http://www.lexa.ru/programs/mod-uid-eng.html) the cookie value actually contains valuable data such as the timestamp the cookie was issued at.

the base64 decoding part is easy :) Was wondering if anyone here can help with the rest of the actions needed in order to parse the data in these cookies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import base64
import socket
import struct


def decode_cookie(cookie):
    """decode a u cookie into an uid

    :param cookie: a cookie value that will be decoded into a uid
    :return: string representing the uid

    This algorithm is for version 2 of http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUseridModule.

    This nginx module follows the apache mod_uid module algorithm, which is
    documented here: http://www.lexa.ru/programs/mod-uid-eng.html.

    """
    # get the raw binary value
    binary_cookie = base64.b64decode(cookie)

    # unpack into 4 parts, each a network byte orderd 32 bit unsigned int
    unsigned_ints = struct.unpack('!4I', binary_cookie)

    # convert from network (big-endian) to host byte (probably little-endian) order
    host_byte_order_ints = [socket.ntohl(i) for i in unsigned_ints]

    # convert to upper case hex value
    uid = 'u=' + ''.join(['{0:08X}'.format(h) for h in host_byte_order_ints])

    return uid


def encode_uid(uid):
    """encode an uid into a u cookie

    :param uid: an uid that will be encoded into a cookie.
    :return: string representing the u cookie

    The algorithm is for version 2 of http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUseridModule.

    This nginx module follows the apache mod_uid module algorithm, which is
    documented here: http://www.lexa.ru/programs/mod-uid-eng.html.

    """
    # get the hex value of the uid
    hex_value = uid.split('=')[1]

    # convert 128 bit string into 4 32 bit integers
    host_byte_order_ints = [int(hex_value[i:i+8], 16) for i in range(0, 32, 8)]

    # convert from host byte (probably little-endian) to network byte (big-endian) order
    unsigned_ints = [socket.htonl(i) for i in host_byte_order_ints]

    # convert to raw binary value
    binary_cookie = struct.pack('!4I', *unsigned_ints)

    # get the base64 version of the cookie
    cookie = base64.b64encode(binary_cookie)

    return cookie
```

Comment: Only after weeks of using this code did I just realize: you translate the ints from network to host byte order, but `struct.unpack` should already be doing that, since you specified `!` as the byte order. Today I tried decoding the meaning of the ints, and only when I omit the `socket.ntohl` line do I get correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Backport of @d3w4rd's answer in PHP just in case someone is looking for it.

```
class NginxUniqid
{
    public static function decodeCookie($cookie)
    {
        return strtoupper(join('', array_map(function ($e) {
            return str_pad(
                base_convert($e, 10, 16),
                8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT
            );
        }, unpack('I4', base64_decode($cookie)))));
    }

    public static function encodeUid($hex)
    {
        return base64_encode(pack(
            'I4',
            base_convert(substr($hex, 0, 8), 16, 10),
            base_convert(substr($hex, 8, 8), 16, 10),
            base_convert(substr($hex, 16, 8), 16, 10),
            base_convert(substr($hex, 24, 8), 16, 10)
        ));
    }
}
```